# Altitude of the parallelogram

Tags: coordinate-systems

The points $A(4, -2)$, $B(7, 2)$, $C(0,9)$, and $D(-3,5)$ form a parallelogram. Find the length of the altitude of this parallelogram with respect to the base $AB$.

Comment: Welcome to stackexchange. You're more likely to get answers rather than downvotes or votes to close if you edit the question to show what you tried and where you are stuck. Use mathjax please: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: You can draw a picture. It helps.

Answer (score 0):

**HINT**

Find the area by the **cross product**

$$S=|\vec v_1 \times \vec v_2|=|\vec v_1||\vec v_2|\sin \theta$$

with

$$v_1=(x_1,y_1,z_1)\;,\;\;\;v_2=(x_2,y_2,z_2)$$

$$v_1\times v_2:=\begin{vmatrix}\vec i&\vec j&\vec k\\x_1&y_1&z_1\\x_2&y_2&z_2\end{vmatrix}=(y_1z_2-z_1y_2\,,\,x_2z_1-x_1z_2\,,\,x_1y_2-x_2y_1)$$

and then $$h=\frac{S}{|AB|}$$